# How to delete memory taken up by deepspeed engine

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to fine-tune Llama-7B on a variety of samples from my dataset, and evaluate on test samples. Llama-7B cannot be trained natively on my GPU, so I am using deepspeed to fine-tune it, as shown in the code below.

I call the train() function several times for different data samples. I found that although the code succeeds to train/fine-tune on the first example, it runs out of memory for the second. As can be seen, I included several print statements (with get_gpu_memory_usage() using nvidia-smi to get memory) to analyze memory throughout the code.

```
def train(tokenizer, model, device, loader, optimizer, model_params):
    print('GPU MEMORY USAGE BEFORE ENGINE CREATED')
    print(get_gpu_memory_usage())
    model.train()
    model, optimizer, _, _ = deepspeed.initialize(model=model, model_parameters=model.parameters(), config=model_params['DEEPSPEED_CONFIG'])
    print('GPU MEMORY USAGE AFTER INITIALIZING ENGINE')
    print(get_gpu_memory_usage())
    outputs = model(...)
    loss = outputs[0]
    print('GPU MEMORY USAGE DURING STEP')
    print(get_gpu_memory_usage())
    # optimizer.zero_grad()
    model.backward(loss)
    # loss.backward()
    model.step()
    # optimizer.step()
    optimizer = None
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    print('GPU MEMORY USAGE AFTER CLEARING CACHE')
    print(get_gpu_memory_usage())

    return losses
```

I found that each time train() is called, the initial memory from the first get_gpu_memory_usage() call (under 'GPU MEMORY USAGE BEFORE ENGINE CREATED') increases; for example, the first time I call train() the memory is 13MB, then 7000MB for the second, then 14000 MB, and so on. When I execute the non-deep speed version of this code on a smaller model (exact same code, except comment out the deepspeed lines and un-comment out optimizer.zero_grad(), loss.backward(), and optimizer.step()), the memory is constant each time I call train().

Therefore, it seems that the things created by deepspeed.initialize() are not being cleared properly from GPU memory. I have tried emptying cuda cache, as can be seen, and have tried deleting objects, etc. - none of this has helped. How can I delete all of the memory taken by the deepspeed objects?

Answer (score 0):

DeepSpeed developer here!

You don't share your DeepSpeed config, but I'm going to guess you are using ZeRO stage 3? I ran into this issue today as well. Turns out we had a memory leak when using ZeRO stage 3. We have a fix and it will be merged into DeepSpeed soon: https://github.com/microsoft/DeepSpeed/pull/3903

Also, for future bugs we encourage you to open an issue on our GitHub repo: https://github.com/microsoft/DeepSpeed/issues